# Codeigniter form_validations won't show any validation_errors message

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm using codeigniter form_validation, but it won't show any validation_errors message, this is my input tag named "name", I have already echo'd the validation_errors

```
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
     <form action="" method="">
          <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
          </div>
```

this is my method to check if form_validation is correct

```
public function Add() { 

        $data['title'] = 'Add Student Form';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('student/add');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
```

Why do I get no validation_errors message?

Comment: You have given the wrong attribute name in input tag. Please correct it to name

Comment: `name="nama"` should be `name="name"`

Comment: @SurajSingh i'm sorry it's a typo, in my code i named it "name" for both of method or form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you didn't specify what kind of method you are going to use. is it **POST** or **GET** ?.

In your case use the method `POST`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: oh yess, i forgot to put that , it is work perfect many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Input Type name is as per you mentioned in the form validation set rules .. also you have printed validation_errors() .

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="nama">
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
```

Comment: i'm sorry it's a typo, in my code i named it "name" for both of method or form, and still show nothing

Comment: you are not printing the validation_errors() 
<?= echo validation_errors(); ?>

Comment: i have, there above the form tag

Comment: @Villian  u have but there is no echo word present there to print.

Comment: i put <?= echo validation_errors() ?> , it getting error unexpected echo

Comment: i thought <?= is equal to <?php echo, am i correct?

Comment: @Villian my bad .  try printing validation_errors() in controller
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            echo "<pre><br>";
            print_r(validation_errors());
            echo "<br></pre>";
            exit;
        }

Comment: it shows nothing, maybe i need to re write the code or something, so i can figure out what's the error, thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: <form action="" method="POST">
as written by @curiosity

Comment: @Villian it happens :D